# how to drop part of array without allocationg new memory?

Tags: c#

I have byte array. I need to drop first 4 bytes, like that:

```
byte[] newArray = new byte[byteArray.Length - 4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArray, 4, newArray, 0, byteArray.Length - 4);
```

But can I just move pointer in C/C++ style? :

```
byte[] byteMsg = byteArray + 4;
```

I do not want to allocate extra memory until absolutely requried because this code is executed pretty often.

**upd:** I receive data from Socket so I probably should just use another version of Receive `count = s.Receive(byteArray);`

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that. A .NET array is always of a fixed size, and you can't do pointer arithmetic on it outside unsafe code.

Try using [`ArraySegment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) instead

Comment: thanks, my data comes from `Socket.Receive`, probably I just should use another version of overloaded method, probably this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kw22c6h2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry, the GC will take care of cleaning up the memory that you're no longer using provided it is not being referenced.

Arrays in C# are immutable.  You can't modify them, so if you need to drop the first 4 bytes then you're going to have to reallocate.  As thecoop suggests, I'd take a look at `ArraySegment` and use that to pass around to other functions, if these first 4 bytes are not important to you.

It's also worth noting that yes, in C++, we'd use a bit of pointer arithmetic, but definitely keep hold of the original pointer, less we end up de-allocated and losing 4 bytes to the Demons :)

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the Byte Array untouched and use a MemoryStream and it's offset capability. this won't change your array and you have the ability to skip the first n bytes.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
// do whatever you want with the memory stream
```